# Custom menu item for ActionBar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is it possible to create for the action bar a menu item with a counter
on it?

I mean like when you get a message on whatsapp and you have the red 
circle with the number of messages?

I have an action bar with a notification symbole (menu item) and I want to 
add on it's top - right corner a textView with the drawable I've created as it's background.

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-ActionItemBadge)

Comment: @calvinfly wow thanks :)